# Reduce video size in android without using FFMPEG

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

In my Android  application I need to reduce video size and then send it to a server.
Is there any faster way than using FFMPEG.

Thanks.

Comment: Video compression is inherently slow – it can mostly be made faster by intentionally losing quality.

Comment: see [MediaCodec](https://github.com/fishwjy/VideoCompressor)